# Wrong positioning of images inside tikzpicture with XeLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, positioning, pdftex

Consider following code:

```
   \tikzstyle{box}=[draw, fill=brown!40, text width=7em,
        text centered, minimum height=7em, rounded corners]
    \tikzstyle{usb}=[draw, fill=blue!40, text width=3em,
        text centered, minimum height=3em]
    \pgfdeclareimage[width=10em]{smarthomes}{smarthomes}
    \pgfdeclareimage[width=10em]{ekg}{ekg}
    \pgfdeclareimage[width=10em]{quadro}{quadro}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (and) [box] {first device};
        \path (and)+(5.5em,0) node (usb) [usb] {USB};
        \path (and)+(11em,0) node (mk) [box,fill=green!40] {second device};


        \path (and)+(25em,10em) node (home) [] {\pgftext{\pgfuseimage{smarthomes}}};
        \path (and)+(25em,0) node (quadro) [] {\pgfbox[center,center]{\pgfuseimage{quadro}}};
        \path (and)+(25em,-10em) node (ekg) [] {\pgfbox[center,center]{\pgfuseimage{ekg}}};

        \draw [thick] (mk.east) to ($(home) - (5em,0)$);
        \draw [thick] (mk.east) to ($(quadro) - (5em,0)$);
        \draw [thick] (mk.east) to ($(ekg) - (5em,0)$);

   \end{tikzpicture}
```

When I use PDFLaTeX all is right, but if I use XeLaTeX images in appropriate nodes are not positioned.

Comment: Note: TeXLive's XeLaTeX does not support clipping. MikTeX' XeLaTeX does not  support clipping and opacity.

Comment: It seems like a bug in the XeTeX driver. If I use `\includegraphics` (but no `\pfgtext` or `\pgfbox`) the images are correctly placed.

Comment: @egreg I'd say that your comment is the answer here: could you convert it?

Comment: Has this bug being reported to xetex developers?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like a bug in the XeTeX driver. If I use `\includegraphics` (but no `\pfgtext` or `\pgfbox`) the images are correctly placed.