# includegraphics inside a TikZ node with XeLaTeX is incorrectly positioned when width or height is given

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, xetex

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

a\includegraphics[height=100pt]{example-image-10x16}b

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west] at (0,0) {a\includegraphics[height=100pt]{example-image-10x16}b};
\fill[red] (0,0) circle[radius=.1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Run with `pdflatex` and it compiles just fine.  Run with `xelatex` and the image in the node is displaced.  It appears to be where the included graphic is located, since the `a` and `b` are always in the correct place.  It also has something to do with the explicit `height=100pt` since removing that also fixes the problem (`width=<something>` also causes the problem to occur).

[image: Displaced image]

1. What's happening?
2. How can I make it stop?

---

Note that the following are related:

1. [Wrong positioning of images inside tikzpicture with XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56937/86)
2. [Switching from PDFLaTeX to XeLaTeX is messing with my pgftext coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101379/86)

but I'm already in the situation of the answers given there.

Nor does the answer to [Centering full-page Tikz image on page without margins with xelatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55362/86) work.

---

*Edit*: Following on from David and Harish's comments, I updated TL2013 and PGF.  With the PGF that comes with TL2013 then it compiles correctly.  With the CVS version of PGF then it does *not*.  So the problem appears to lie with the PGF code for xelatex.  I also discovered that the page changed from A4 paper (TL version of PGF) to letter paper (CVS version).  As a Brit, my TL is set to produce A4 by default.  Manually putting in `a4paper` changes the paper size back to A4, but doesn't correct the image displacement.  So my guess is that the error is in PGF's driver file for XeTeX.

Comment: works for me with a tL2013 updated today

Comment: Strange. I get it right with miktex 2.9.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser ... I'm updating TL2013 and PGF as I type, will report back.

Comment: Edited in the results of a bit of research ...

Comment: Is this related to the bug you have reported and closed by Till after a weird research about dvi driver of XeTeX? Maybe you can answer this if that's the case?

Comment: @percusse I'll check with the latest PGF and see if it's fixed.

Comment: @percusse Yes, this is now fixed in PGF.  Shall we close this one?

Comment: This has now been fixed in the CVS version of PGF.